# My laptop touchpad is not working properly using ubuntu 18.04

Tags: xorg, touchpad, dependencies, synaptics

I have run these command on terminal:
**sudo apt-get update**
then *sudo apt-get install xserver-xorg-input-synaptics*
After executing result is shown below
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
xserver-xorg-input-synaptics : Depends: xserver-xorg-core (>= 2:1.18.99.901)
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.

Now someone please tell me that what should I do next.

Answer (score 0):

You can try `sudo apt install xserver-xorg-core` to install the missing dependency,
if there are errors try `sudo apt -f install` and report the output.
Otherwise retry `sudo apt install xserver-xorg-input-synaptics`.